# Polymorphic associations with multiple has_many associations between the same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphism

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the associations worked out between three models - Team, User, and Request.

- A team has users.
- A user can create requests.
- A request can be assigned to either a team or a user.

Here are the models as I Currently have them:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :created_requests, as: :creator, class_name: "Request"
  has_many :assigned_requests, class_name: "Request", as: :assignable, foreign_key: "assignable_id"
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :assigned_requests, class_name: "Request", as: :assignable, foreign_key: "assignable_id"
end

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :assignable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Most of the relations seem to work, but I run into a problem trying to view a user's created_requests. The error that I get is **"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column requests.creator_type does not exist"**

There is no creator_type since the relationship between users and created_requests isn't polymorphic - only the relationship between users/teams and assigned_requests is polymorphic. How would I specify this in the model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `as: :creator` from the `has_many :created_requests, as: :creator, class_name: "Request"` in the `User` model. The `as:` is only for polymorphic associations, and if it's not a polymorphic association as you say, then you shouldn't have that in there.